# Can I redirect to a URL that includes a unicode character in JSF?

Tags: url, unicode, jsf-2.2

Can I do a redirect like this:

```
FacesContext context= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String contextPath = context.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();
context.getExternalContext().redirect(contextPath+"/taşıma");
```

When `contextPath/taşıma` is already defined in URL rewrite rules?
When I enter into the URL `contextPath/taşıma` it goes to the page `transportation.xhtml` with no problem but in the redirect it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `URLEncoder`:

```
context.getExternalContext().redirect(contextPath+"/"+URLEncoder.encode(stringToEncode, "UTF-8"));
```